# Inserting HREF in modal using php don't work

Tags: php, hyperlink, modal-dialog, href

When I try to click the emp['rec_no'] value, it does not display the content of rec_no, my modal window is empty. The content of $rec_no should display inside the modal window.

Thank you so much for your help in advanced

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Reservation Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <?php
     $rec_no = $_GET['rec_no'];
     $alumni_open = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE rec_no = '$rec_no'";
     $alumni_query = mysqli_query($connector,$alumni_open) or die 
     (mysqli_error());
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($alumni_query);
     echo $row['rec_no']; ?>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MODAL END -->

<!--TRIGGER WHERE THE USER WILL CLICK THE VALUE OF $emp['rec_no'] -->
<a href="#myModal<?php echo $emp['rec_no'];?>" data-toggle='modal' data- 
   target='#myModal'><div align="center"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
   style="color:#FFFFFF"></div>
```

Comment: Does the source generate correctly? You are open to SQL injections, parameterize query and use prepared statements. `mysqli_error` also requires a connections string

Comment: Yes it runs but it does not recognized the value of rec_no.. by the way what are paremeters to avoid sql injections I am new to this development

Comment: Enable error reporting also. You're not using the correct code in the HTML to "GET" the record.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php basically `SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE rec_no = ?`, change your functions, and bind `$rec_no`.

Comment: Sorry, what u mean by functions sir

Comment: Your question is not clarity

Comment: @MetySoriano Follow the link